# Is it possible to invoke a Java Webservice from a C# client (RestClient)

Tags: c#, webservice-client

I am trying to invoke a webservice using a C# client. The current code in C# is to create the RestClient and send the request.

```
string url = "http://test:8080/";
var client = new RestClient(url);
var req = new RestRequest("test/", Method.POST);
req.AddParameter("", data, ParameterType.RequestBody);


//Add authentication to request

//execute client request
IRestResponse testresponse = client.Execute(req);
```

The following is the code from the web service.

```
    @WebService(endpointInterface = "com.test.ws.test")
    public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService
    {
    private TestUpdater TestUpdater;

    private Posting1Status postingStatus;

    @Override
    public Posting1Status setTestentry(Testentry entry) 
    {
        MessageContext mctx = wsctx.getMessageContext();
        //get detail from request headers
        Map http_headers = (Map) mctx.get(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS);
        List userList = (List) http_headers.get("Username");
        List passList = (List) http_headers.get("Password");

        String username = "";
        String password = "";

        if(userList!=null){
              //get username
              username = userList.get(0).toString();
        }

        if(passList!=null){
              //get password
              password = passList.get(0).toString();
        }     

        if (username.equals("roji") && password.equals("roji1"))
        {
        }
    }
```

Before adding this authentication code the C# client was able to access the webservice and run the code as expected. But i cannot seem to find the headers or i'm passing them in incorrectly. Does anyone have any solutions maybe, or if i'm doing this the correct way.

Comment: So have you looked at the exact request that the C# code is making? (And do you have to have plaintext username/password? That's definitely not ideal as an authentication scheme.)

Comment: You don't seem to be adding headers to the `RestRequest` in C#. Did you miss that?

Comment: @daisy i'm just trying to pass a basic authentication at the minute, afterwards I can improve the passwords and make it more secure.

Comment: @Dan I have tried the following headers but the also didn't work
req.AddHeader("Username", "roji");
req.AddHeader("Password", "roji1");

Comment: Rather than trying to implement authentication yourself, I would strongly advise you to look into the authentication modules provided by the framework you're using. They're likely to provide far more effective security *and* it's likely that you'll be able to interoperate with C# more easily too.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement this basic class i which you'll find how to add as much key-value pairs you need in the header

```
public static class RestserviceClient
{
    static string URL_ENDPOINT = "www.endpoint.com/service/method";

    public static dynamic CallService(string jsonToSend)
    {

        var url = new Uri(URL_ENDPOINT);
        var connection = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        //Timeout, proxy and other configurations
        connection.Timeout = 120000;
        connection.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
        connection.KeepAlive = true;
        connection.ContentType = string.Format("application/json");

        //Restful call in this case POST
        connection.Method = "POST";
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

        //IMPORTANT --> Add as much key-value headers you need
        connection.Headers.Add("firstHeaderKey", "firstHeader Value");
        connection.Headers.Add("secondHeaderKey", "secondHeader Value");

        using (var outStream = connection.GetRequestStream())
        {
            var docStream = new StreamWriter(outStream);
            outStream.AppendJson(jsonToSend);
            docStream.Flush();
            docStream.Close();
        }

        string retVal;
        var res = connection.GetResponse();
        using (var resStream = res.GetResponseStream())
        {
            if (resStream == null) return null;
            var reader = new StreamReader(resStream);
            retVal = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    public static void AppendJson(this Stream dos, String json)
    {
        var bld = new StringBuilder();
        bld.Append(json);
        var a = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bld.ToString());
        dos.Write(a, 0, a.Length);
    }
}
```